# How to show different background color for angular-ui-switch

Tags: css, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have questions about angular-ui-switch (http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-ui-switch). I would like to let the switch show different background colors based on the  name of each object. Below is what I did:

-- I the color defined in the css file as below:

```
.switch {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: rgb(223, 223, 223) 0px 0px 0px 0px inset;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-out all;
  top: -1px;
}
.switch small {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-out all;
}
.switch.checked {
  background: rgb(100, 189, 99);
  border-color: rgb(100, 189, 99);
}
.switch.checked small {
  left: 22px;
}

.switch.red
{
    background: rgb(187, 2, 2);
}
.switch.primary
{
    background: rgb(74, 124, 173);
}
.switch.green
{
    background: rgb(16, 124, 42);
}
```

Here is my Html view:

```
<div ng-repeat="es in allEventSources track by $index" style="margin-top:5px; vertical-align:middle; line-height:40px">
                                    <span style="float:left; margin-top:8px; font-size:16px;">{{es.name}}:</span>
                                    <span style="float:right; margin-top:8px;"><switch class="{red: es.name=='Boston', primary: es.name=='New York', green: es.name=='Washington' }" ng-model="es.enabled"  ng-click="toggleEventSource(es)"></switch></span>

                                </div>
```

However, my switch is always ONLY showing the green as the background color.  Does any one here know why?

Any help would be great appreciated.  Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

(tested with `angular-ui-switch` version `0.1.0`)

If you edit `.switch.checked` css class, you will globally alter all switches.

However, you could tweak the style of individual `<switch/>` with `ng-style` attribute, in order to override background color resulting from `.switch.checked` css class being applied to switches in "on" state.

For example:

`<switch id="enabled" name="enabled" ng-model="enabled" ng-style="getStyle(enabled, 'red')" />`

In your angular controller define a function:

```
$scope.getStyle = function(enabled, color) {
 return {
  'background': enabled?color:'white',
  'border-color': enabled?color:'white'
 }
}
```